# How to run an API in a loop for multiple records in sequential order

Tags: angularjs, node.js

There is a HTML table in which data is supposed to come through a node API.

```
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Row1</th>
            <th>Row2</th>
            <th>Row3</th>
            <th>Row4</th>
            <th>Row5</th>
            <th>Row6</th>
            <th>Row7</th>
            <th>Row8</th>
            <th>Row9</th>
            <th>Row10</th>
            <th>Row11</th>
            <th>Row12</th>
            <th>Row13</th>
            <th>Row14</th>
            <th>Row15</th>
            <th>Row16</th>
            <th>Row17</th>
            <th>Row18</th>
            <th>Row19</th>
            <th>Row20</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="row in array track by $index">
            <td>{{row.value1}}</td>
            <td>{{row.value2}}</td>
            <td>{{row.value3}}</td>
            <td>{{row.value4}}</td>
            <td>{{row.value5}}</td>
            <td>{{row.value6}}</td>
            <td>{{row.value7}}</td>
            <td>{{row.value8}}</td>
            <td>{{row.value9}}</td>
            <td>{{row.value10}}</td>
            <td>{{row.value11}}</td>
            <td>{{row.value12}}</td>
            <td>{{row.value13}}</td>
            <td>{{row.value14}}</td>
            <td>{{row.value15}}</td>
            <td>{{row.value16}}</td>
            <td>{{row.value17}}</td>
            <td>{{row.value18}}</td>
            <td>{{row.value19}}</td>
            <td>{{row.value20}}</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

My angular directive code:-

```
ApiServices.getArrayData(value).then(function (response) {
            scope.array = response.data; // This is an array of objects
            for (var i = 0; i < scope.array.length; i++) {
                ApiServices.getOtherDetails(scope.array[i].id).then(function (response) {
                    scope.array[i].value2 = response.data.value2;
                    scope.array[i].value3 = response.data.value3;
                    scope.array[i].value5 = response.data.value5;
                    scope.array[i].value8 = response.data.value8;
                    scope.array[i].value11 = response.data.value11;
                    scope.array[i].value12 = response.data.value12;
                    scope.array[i].value13 = response.data.value13;
                    scope.array[i].value18 = response.data.value18;
                    scope.array[i].value20 = response.data.value20;
                });
            }
})
```

In the above code:- The getArrayData API brings data for only some rows. For other rows I am bringing data from getOtherDetails API which takes value from scope.array[i].id for each record.

The issue I am facing here is the loop is not working in the flow I want. It first iterates the for loop only and then it loops the inner API. So the data is showed in one record only.

Is there any way I can make the flow of loop the way I coded it. Or is there any other way to achieve what I am trying to do here. Please suggest any solution.

Comment: This is happening because on async nature of node.js

Comment: Any solution for that. Should I use callback method for this?

Comment: @shreyagupta change from for (var i = 0 to for (let i = 0

Comment: @spiritwalker. I have tried using let instead of var which serves the purpose but it loads data after scope.array loads which is inconsistent. Is there any way I can combine both and show it together. Also, there are some records which left empty. Do you know why?

Comment: @shreyagupta when you say inconsistent I guess you are referring to UI look and feel because of rendering timing. Is that right? So you prefer one big chunk page rendering rather than async partial renderings?

Comment: @shreyagupta if you just want to show all data at once, there are two simple ways of doing so.1. Add a single server api to return all data with one get request. 2. Or You can use angular ng-show to achieve it, so check if all data has been loaded then show them all together.

Comment: If neither of those two approaches above could satisfy you, I guess you can create a temporary variable something like fakeScopeArray = response.data to store TR data, and then until TD data has been loaded, you assign it to real scope variable like scope.array = fakeScopeArray

Comment: @shreyagupta, I can't tell about empty record, perhaps you need to do some console.log to find out why

Comment: @ spiritwalker, In for loop (let say for 5 times), first getOtherDetails API runs 5 times and then the remaining lines of code runs but for only 4 times. So, there is amis off one record which doesn't show in UI. And there are many records which are empty.I do not understand why?

Comment: I've updated my answer to add another example to simulate your case. it runs without any problem. I'm not sure why the "the remaining lines of code runs but for only 4 times", one possibility is that one of promise resolved with error(or say rejected). So add a error handler to check. something like .then(result=>{}, error=>{}). About empty records could that be your server issue?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [async.mapSeries](https://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html#mapSeries) of [async](https://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html) module.
That will execute your item one by one and at final callback you can send your respond.

I am just giving you a simple example, how it works with `setTimeout` function.
you will get your result in final callback

```
async.mapSeries([1,2,3,4],function(item,cb){
setTimeout(function(){
console.log(item);
},1000)
cb();
},function(err,result){
console.log(result)
})
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is related to javascript closure. since callback is async therefore all callbacks will get same value of i.

```js
const test = (callback) => {
setTimeout(callback, 1000)
}

const count = 3

//wrong
for(var i = 0; i < count; i++){

test(() => {
   console.log("i: " + i)
  })
}

//right es5 - using ugly self-invoking function
for(var j = 0; j < count; j++){
(function(j){
 test(() => {
    console.log("j: " + j)
  })
})(j);
}

//right es6
for( let k = 0; k < count; k++){

test(() => {
   console.log("k: " + k)
  })
}
```

to simulate and test your scenario.

```js
angular.module("app", []).controller("testController", function($scope, $q) {
  $scope.array = []
  //simulate api
  $scope.getArrayData = () => {
    const deferred = $q.defer();
    deferred.resolve([{
      id: 1
    }, {
      id: 2
    }, {
      id: 3
    }, {
      id: 4
    }, {
      id: 5
    }])
    return deferred.promise
  }

  //simulate api
  $scope.getOtherDetails = (id) => {
    const deferred = $q.defer();
    deferred.resolve({
      data: {
        id: id,
        value1: id + 'value1',
        value2: id + 'value2',
        value3: id + 'value3',
        value4: id + 'value4',
        value5: id + 'value5'
      }
    })
    return deferred.promise
  }

  $scope.render = () => {
    $scope.getArrayData().then((response) => {
      $scope.array = response
      for (let i = 0; i < response.length; i++) {
        $scope.getOtherDetails(response[i].id).then(response => {
          $scope.array[i].value1 = response.data.value1
          $scope.array[i].value2 = response.data.value2
          $scope.array[i].value3 = response.data.value3
          $scope.array[i].value4 = response.data.value4
          $scope.array[i].value5 = response.data.value5
        })
      }
    })
  }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app">
  <div ng-controller="testController">
    <button ng-click="render()" style="width:100px; height:30px;">render</button>
    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Row1</th>
          <th>Row2</th>
          <th>Row3</th>
          <th>Row4</th>
          <th>Row5</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="row in array track by $index">
          <td>{{row.value1}}</td>
          <td>{{row.value2}}</td>
          <td>{{row.value3}}</td>
          <td>{{row.value4}}</td>
          <td>{{row.value5}}</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```